# Appending a Character to a textField while typing

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextfield

The textField is supposed to do the following:

```
User types "w" -> textField: "w?"  
User types "ho are you" -> textfield: "who are you?
```

Right now for every character that is typed a "?" is added before it.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let text = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    let newLength = text.characters.count

    if newLength <= 25 {
        cLabel.text = String(25 - newLength)
        if text.isEmpty { //Checking if the input field is not empty
            ahskButton.userInteractionEnabled = false //Disabling the button
            ahskButton.enabled = false

        } else {
            ahskButton.userInteractionEnabled = true //Enabling the button
            ahskButton.enabled = true
            textField.text! += "?" //NOT WORKING
        }

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @luk2302 i want the questionmark to be appended to the end of the string that the user is typing while the user is typing inside the textField. also i need a button to be disabled als long as the textField is empty and the number of characters needs to be limited and shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what did the Trick for me:

```
@IBAction func textEdit(sender: UITextField) {

        let quest:Character = "?" // Character to append

        if sender.text!.characters.count == 1 { // if textfield has exactly one character

            if sender.text! != "?" { // if this character is not "?"

                self.ahskField.text!.append(quest) // append "?"

                // the following repositions the cursor in front of the "?"

                // only if there is a currently selected range
                if let selectedRange = sender.selectedTextRange {

                // and only if the new position is valid
                if let newPosition = sender.positionFromPosition(selectedRange.start, inDirection: UITextLayoutDirection.Left, offset: 1) {

                // set the new position
                sender.selectedTextRange = sender.textRangeFromPosition(newPosition, toPosition: newPosition)
                    }
                }

            } else {

                sender.text = "" //Clear TextField

                cLabel.text = "25" //Reset textcount Label

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the name of the delegate method you're implementing: `shouldReplaceCharactersInRange`.

You're overriding it as if it were `didReplaceCharactersInRange`.

The replacing of the characters doesn't happen till **after** you return from this method, if at all (depending on the return value).

If you want to alter the text yourself in this method, you should return `false` from the method.

EDIT:
If you return false, the text won't change automatically.

You currently append the text of the textField with a question mark, but don't add the characters the user is trying to input.

You probably want to make it more like:

`textField.text! = text + '?'`

Essentially, you want to manually set the text of `textField` to the correct string each time this method is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MatthewHallatt. The method im implementing is actually called `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` If I return `false` from the the method every character typed is replaces by an "?"

Comment: Check my edit - I probably didn't explain well enough